# CodeIgniter error, result_array and foreach error

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, foreach

Below are my codes and errors that come up with my CodeIgniter. 
My error is Fatal error: Call to a member function result_array() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\CodeIgniter\application\models\news_model.php on line 15
I found a way around that but then I get an error that something is wrong in my foreach statement in my index.php file line 1
Anyone have any idea where the error maybe?

news_model.php (model)

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class News_model extends CI_Model
{

public function __construct()
{
    $this->load->database();
}

public function get_news($slug = FALSE)
{
    if ($slug === FALSE)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('news');
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    $query = $this->db->get_where('news', array('slug' => $slug));
    return $query->row_array();
}

public function set_news()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');

    $slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE);

    $data = array(
        'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
        'slug' => $slug,
        'text' => $this->input->post('text')
    );

    return $this->db->insert('news', $data);
}


public function delete_news($id) 
{
    $this->db->delete('news', array('id' => $id));
}
}
```

news.php (controller)

```
<?php
class News extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('news_model');
}

public function index()
{
    $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news();
    $data['title'] = 'News archive';

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('news/index', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}

public function view($slug)
{
    $data['news_item'] = $this->news_model->get_news($slug);

    if (empty($data['news_item']))
    {
        show_404();
    }

    $data['title'] = $data['news_item']['title'];

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('news/view', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}

public function create()
{
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $data['title'] = 'Create a news item';

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('text', 'text', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('news/create');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');

    }
    else
    {
        $this->news_model->set_news();
        $this->load->view('news/success');
    }
}
}
```

index.php (view)

```
<?php foreach ($news as $news_item): ?>

<h2><?php echo $news_item['title'] ?></h2>
<div id="main">
    <?php echo $news_item['text'] ?>
</div>
<p><a href="news/<?php echo $news_item['slug'] ?>">View article</a></p>

<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>news/delete/<?php echo $news_item['id'] ?>">Delete article</a>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Are there any records in the news table?

Comment: I'd imagine if the query returns an empty set, `result_array()` should return an empty array.

Comment: yes there are records. I am following codeIgniter why should it return an empty array when the array has fields?

Answer (score 1):

Try returning $query->result() rather than $query->result_array() and check if it is working.
Also you will need to change in your foreach loop while displaying results.

Answer (score 0):

in your view you looping, $news variable as a **result_array**,

but in your model for : **function get_news($slug = FALSE)**,

if **$slug !== FALSE** your return **row_array**

I suggest you to return **result_array()**, so your view-code does not confuse.

```
public function get_news($slug = FALSE)
{
    if ($slug === FALSE)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('news');
        return $query->result_array(); //return result_array()
    }

    $query = $this->db->get_where('news', array('slug' => $slug));
    return $query->result_array(); //return result_array()
}
```